# How to use IPv6 internet addresses on Linux with systemd-networkd

Tags: networking, debian, ipv6, systemd

I have a problem with my providers internet router using IPv6 addresses and I realized that I do not really understand how to use IPv6 addresses. To get an idea I like to ask how to use the different IPv6 address types for example to route traffic from one host to another with only one router between them.

```
Using three nodes:
┏━━━━━━━━━┓   addr: 2001:db8:0:10::1/64    addr: 2001.db8:0:20::1/64   ┏━━━━━━━━━┓
┃ host-a  ┃                      ╲ ┏━━━━━━━━━━┓ ╱                      ┃ host-b  ┃
┃     eth0┣════════════════════════┫eth0  eth1┣════════════════════════┫eth0     ┃
┗━━━━━━━━━┛ ╲                      ┃  router  ┃                      ╱ ┗━━━━━━━━━┛
  addr: 2001:db8:0:10::2/64        ┗━━━━━━━━━━┛         addr: 2001:db8:0:20::2/64
subnet: 2001:db8:0:10::/64                            subnet: 2001:db8:0:20::/64
```

How do I have to setup it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't found so far a simple example like this to understand the basics with reference to the sources. It's more a prove of concept but it has taken me some effort, so I will share it with the community step by step.

### Preparations

I use three virtual machines on KVM (Kernel-based Virtual Machine), all with Debian 11 (bullseye, at this time testing version) and using terminology from [RFC 2460](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2460#section-2):
**Node** is an interface enabled for IPv6.
**Router** is any node that forwards IPv6 packets that are not expressly addressed to it.
**Host** is any node that’s not a router.

We need some helper programs that should be installed as long we have internet access on the nodes before reconfiguring its network interfaces for testing. On all nodes install `radvdump` and on the router install `radvd`. Be sure that `radvd` is disabled, otherwise it will confuse the testing. I will use `tcpdump` to look what's going on on the network, so install it on the router. On Debian I do all of this with:

```
~$ sudo apt install radvdump        # on hosts and router
router ~$ sudo apt install radvd    # only on the router
router ~$ sudo systemctl disable --now radvd.service
router ~$ sudo apt install tcpdump  # only on the router
```

I use the IPv6 Address Prefix **2001:DB8::/32** Reserved for Documentation ([RFC 3849](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3849)) that is usable for valid global unicast addresses but not routed to the internet.

To have things by hand, here are some specifications:

There are some address types used ([RFC 4291](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4291#section-2.4))

```
Unspecified          ::/128
Loopback             ::1/128
default route        ::/0
Multicast            FF00::/8
Unique Local unicast FD00::/8
Global Unicast       (everything else)
Global Anycast       (same as Global Unicast)   not used in this example
```

Scope of Multicast addresses ([RFC 4291](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4291#section-2.7)):

```
FF00::  reserved
FF01::  Interface-Local scope
FF02::  Link-Local scope
FF03::  reserved
FF04::  Admin-Local scope
FF05::  Site-Local scope
FF06:: to FF07::  (unassigned)
FF08::  Organization-Local scope
FF09:: to FF0D::  (unassigned)
FF0E::  Global scope
FF0F::  reserved
```

Well-known IPv6 multicast addresses (extract - complete list at [IANA](https://www.iana.org/assignments/ipv6-multicast-addresses/ipv6-multicast-addresses.xhtml)):

```
ff02::1     all nodes
ff02::2     all routers
ff02::5     all OSPF (Open Shortest Path First) routers
ff02::6     all OSPF DRs (OSPF Designated Routers)
ff02::9     all RIP (Routing Information Protocol) routers
ff02::a     all EIGRP (Enhanced Interior Gateway Routing Protocol) routers
ff02::c     SSDP (Simple Service Discovery Protocol)
ff02::d     all PIM (Protocol Independent Multicast) routers
ff02::f     UPNP (Universal Plug and Play) devices
ff02::11    all homenet nodes
ff02::12    VRRP (Virtual Router Redundancy Protocol)
ff02::16    all MLDv2-capable routers
ff02::1a    all RPL (Routing Protocol for Low-Power and Lossy Networks) routers (used in Internet of Things (IoT) devices)
ff02::fb    multicast DNS IPv6
ff02::101   network time (NTP)
ff02::1:2   all DHCP agents
ff02::1:3   LLMNR (Link-Local Multicast Name Resolution)
ff02:0:0:0:0:1:ff00::/104   solicited node address
ff02:0:0:0:0:1-2:ff00::/104     node information query
ff05::1:3   all DHCP server (site)
ff05::101   all NTP server (site)
```

Enable **systemd-networkd** by following

Section **Quick Step** at [Use systemd-networkd for general networking](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/108593/79866), then come back here.

I will have everything disabled so we can see what is needed and enable it step by step. On `host-a` and `host-b` use this network file:

```
host-? ~$ sudo -Es   # if not already done
host-? ~# cat > /etc/systemd/network/04-wired.network <<EOF
[Match]
Name=eth0

[Network]
# on host-a uncomment
#Address=2001:db8:0:10::2/64
# on host-b uncomment
#Address=2001:db8:0:20::2/64
IPv6AcceptRA=no
LinkLocalAddressing=no
EOF
```

On the router use these ones:

```
router ~$ sudo -Es   # if not already done
router ~# cat > /etc/systemd/network/04-eth0.network <<EOF
[Match]
Name=eth0

[Network]
Address=2001:db8:0:10::1/64
IPv6AcceptRA=no
LinkLocalAddressing=no
EOF

router ~# cat > /etc/systemd/network/06-eth1.network <<EOF
[Match]
Name=eth1

[Network]
Address=2001:db8:0:20::1/64
IPv6AcceptRA=no
LinkLocalAddressing=no
EOF
```

### Simple link-local connection

First I will have a look at the direct connection between `host-a` and the `router`. The router is UP and I start `host-a`. `tcpdump` shows me on subnet 2001:db8:0:10/64:

```
host-a ~$ sudo tcpdump -n --number --interface=eth0 ip6 2>/dev/null
    1  23:25:28.211331 IP6 :: > ff02::16: HBH ICMP6, multicast listener report v2, 1 group record(s), length 28
    2  23:25:28.227326 IP6 :: > ff02::16: HBH ICMP6, multicast listener report v2, 2 group record(s), length 48
    3  23:25:28.671386 IP6 :: > ff02::16: HBH ICMP6, multicast listener report v2, 1 group record(s), length 28
    4  23:25:28.735354 IP6 :: > ff02::1:ff00:2: ICMP6, neighbor solicitation, who has 2001:db8:0:10::2, length 32
```

- With package 1-3 `host-a` joins as listener to the multicast group `ff02::16` - all MLDv2-capable routers. Router know now that it want to receive routing messages.
- With package 4 it asked if there is another node with ip address 2001:db8:0:10::2. It isn't because there is no reply. `host-a` can use the address.

Ping to `router` works:

```
host-a ~$ ping6 -n 2001:db8:0:10::1
PING 2001:db8:0:10::1(2001:db8:0:10::1) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 2001:db8:0:10::1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.829 ms
64 bytes from 2001:db8:0:10::1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.863 ms
64 bytes from 2001:db8:0:10::1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.858 ms
--- snip ---
```

### Link-local unicast addresses

In the next step I want to connect to the second interface **eth1** on `router`. For this we need a static route:

```
host-a ~$ sudo ip -6 route add 2001:db8:0:20::/64 via 2001:db8:0:10::1
```

But `ping6 -n 2001:db8:0:20::1` does not work stable:

```
host-a ~$ ping6 -n 2001:db8:0:20::1
PING 2001:db8:0:20::1(2001:db8:0:20::1) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 2001:db8:0:20::1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.881 ms
64 bytes from 2001:db8:0:20::1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.784 ms
64 bytes from 2001:db8:0:20::1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.898 ms
64 bytes from 2001:db8:0:20::1: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.799 ms
64 bytes from 2001:db8:0:20::1: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=0.805 ms
64 bytes from 2001:db8:0:20::1: icmp_seq=6 ttl=64 time=1.13 ms
64 bytes from 2001:db8:0:20::1: icmp_seq=7 ttl=64 time=0.795 ms
64 bytes from 2001:db8:0:20::1: icmp_seq=8 ttl=64 time=0.790 ms
64 bytes from 2001:db8:0:20::1: icmp_seq=9 ttl=64 time=0.793 ms
                                ^^^^^^^^^^
64 bytes from 2001:db8:0:20::1: icmp_seq=55 ttl=64 time=1025 ms
64 bytes from 2001:db8:0:20::1: icmp_seq=56 ttl=64 time=3.26 ms
64 bytes from 2001:db8:0:20::1: icmp_seq=57 ttl=64 time=0.793 ms
64 bytes from 2001:db8:0:20::1: icmp_seq=58 ttl=64 time=0.792 ms
64 bytes from 2001:db8:0:20::1: icmp_seq=59 ttl=64 time=0.789 ms
64 bytes from 2001:db8:0:20::1: icmp_seq=60 ttl=64 time=0.776 ms
64 bytes from 2001:db8:0:20::1: icmp_seq=61 ttl=64 time=0.803 ms
64 bytes from 2001:db8:0:20::1: icmp_seq=62 ttl=64 time=0.801 ms
64 bytes from 2001:db8:0:20::1: icmp_seq=63 ttl=64 time=0.774 ms
64 bytes from 2001:db8:0:20::1: icmp_seq=64 ttl=64 time=0.802 ms
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^
64 bytes from 2001:db8:0:20::1: icmp_seq=110 ttl=64 time=2049 ms
64 bytes from 2001:db8:0:20::1: icmp_seq=111 ttl=64 time=1025 ms
--- snip ---
^C
--- 2001:db8:0:20::1 ping statistics ---
170 packets transmitted, 35 received, 79.4118% packet loss, time 172432ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.774/205.826/2048.843/536.218 ms, pipe 3
```

If you follow the `seq` number you will see with ping delay of 1 sec, that it is interrupted after about 10 sec and repeated after about 45 sec with a packet loss of about 80%. That cannot be called stable.  I do not really understand it but it's good to know about this behavior when looking for troubleshooting. Anyway, it's out of specification because for connections on the link (2001:db8:0:10:2 to 2001:db8:0:10:1) there must be used **link-local addresses** as specified at [RFC 4291 - Link-Local IPv6 Unicast Addresses](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4291#section-2.5.6):

> Link-Local addresses are designed to be used for addressing on a single link for purposes such as automatic address configuration, neighbor discovery, or when no routers are present.

Check for a link-local address on the interface. There is no one:

```
host-a ~$ ip -6 -br addr
lo               UNKNOWN        ::1/128
eth0             UP             2001:db8:0:10::2/64
```

I enable it with setting `LinkLocalAddressing=ipv6` in all `/etc/systemd/network/*.network` files on all nodes, reboot, check and ping:

```
host-a ~$ ip -6 -br addr
lo               UNKNOWN        ::1/128
eth0             UP             2001:db8:0:10::2/64 fe80::5054:ff:febc:adbe/64

router ~$ ip -6 -br addr
lo               UNKNOWN        ::1/128
eth0             UP             2001:db8:0:10::1/64 fe80::5054:ff:fe0f:194e/64
eth1             UP             2001:db8:0:20::1/64 fe80::5054:ff:fe0f:194e/64

host-b ~$ ip -6 -br addr
lo               UNKNOWN        ::1/128
eth0             UP             2001:db8:0:20::2/64 fe80::5054:ff:fe9b:34b9/64

host-a ~$ sudo ip -6 route add 2001:db8:0:20::/64 via 2001:db8:0:10::1
host-a ~$ ping6 -n 2001:db8:0:20::1
PING 2001:db8:0:20::1(2001:db8:0:20::1) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 2001:db8:0:20::1: icmp_seq=9 ttl=64 time=2.08 ms
64 bytes from 2001:db8:0:20::1: icmp_seq=10 ttl=64 time=0.780 ms
64 bytes from 2001:db8:0:20::1: icmp_seq=11 ttl=64 time=0.783 ms
--- snip ---
```

Works.

### Static Routing

If I try to connect from `host-a` to `host-b` then `ping6 -n 2001:db8:0:20::2` fails. That is because the `router` does not forward packages between its interfaces. We have to enable it. Just append `IPForward=ipv6` to a `*.network` file. We also need a static route on `host-b` so it knows where to send the replies to `host-a`. We will do it persistent now. So you will get following `.network` files:

**host-a**

```
host-a ~$ cat /etc/systemd/network/04-wired.network
[Match]
Name=eth0

[Network]
Address=2001:db8:0:10::2/64
IPv6AcceptRA=no
LinkLocalAddressing=ipv6

[Route]
Destination=2001:db8:0:20::/64
Gateway=2001:db8:0:10::1
```

**router**

```
router ~$ cat /etc/systemd/network/04-eth0.network
[Match]
Name=eth0

[Network]
Address=2001:0DB8:0:10::1/64
IPv6AcceptRA=no
LinkLocalAddressing=ipv6
IPForward=ipv6

router ~$ cat /etc/systemd/network/06-eth1.network
[Match]
Name=eth1

[Network]
Address=2001:0DB8:0:20::1/64
IPv6AcceptRA=no
LinkLocalAddressing=ipv6
IPForward=ipv6
```

**host-b**

```
host-b ~$ cat /etc/systemd/network/04-wired.network
[Match]
Name=eth0

[Network]
Address=2001:db8:0:20::2/64
IPv6AcceptRA=no
LinkLocalAddressing=ipv6

[Route]
Destination=2001:db8:0:10::/64
Gateway=2001:db8:0:20::1
```

### Router Advertisement

Static routing is not very comfortable. This is usually done automatically. A host can ask a router for its configuration. To support it you have to enable `IPv6AcceptRA=yes` in its `/etc/systemd/*.network` file. If you do it you will find with `tcpdump` on boot up a host:

```
host-a ~$ sudo tcpdump -n --number --interface=eth0 ip6 2>/dev/null
 1  18:06:20.965014 IP6 :: > ff02::16: HBH ICMP6, multicast listener report v2, 1 group record(s), length 28
 2  18:06:20.976965 IP6 :: > ff02::16: HBH ICMP6, multicast listener report v2, 2 group record(s), length 48
 4  18:06:21.701148 IP6 :: > ff02::1:ffbc:adbe: ICMP6, neighbor solicitation, who has fe80::5054:ff:febc:adbe, length 32
 5  18:06:21.861153 IP6 :: > ff02::1:ff00:2: ICMP6, neighbor solicitation, who has 2001:db8:0:10::2, length 32
 7  18:06:22.725190 IP6 fe80::5054:ff:febc:adbe > ff02::16: HBH ICMP6, multicast listener report v2, 3 group record(s), length 68
 9  18:06:24.225649 IP6 fe80::5054:ff:febc:adbe > ff02::2: ICMP6, router solicitation, length 16
10  18:06:27.851217 IP6 fe80::5054:ff:febc:adbe > ff02::2: ICMP6, router solicitation, length 16
11  18:06:35.087287 IP6 fe80::5054:ff:febc:adbe > ff02::2: ICMP6, router solicitation, length 16
--- snip ---
```

In addition to the already known packages `multicast listener report v2` and `neighbor solicitation` we find `router solicitation` packages. With this message the host is asking to router for an interface configuration. But the `router` does not response so the host is continuing asking. On Linux an IPv6 router does not reply to router solicitations out of the box. It needs an additional service `radvd` to manage this. We have already installed it but disabled it. Using the simple example from Debian `/usr/share/doc/radvd/examples/simple-radvd.conf` we now configure and enable it:

```
router ~$ sudo -Es   # if not already done
router ~# cat > /etc/radvd.conf <<EOF
interface eth0
{
   AdvSendAdvert on;
   prefix 2001:db8:0:10::/64
   {
   };
};

interface eth1
{
   AdvSendAdvert on;
   prefix 2001:db8:0:20::/64
   {
   };
};
EOF

~# systemctl enable radvd.service
```

Because we expect that the hosts get their configuration from the router now, we have to remove the manual settings from its `.network` files. They should look as follows:

**host-a** and **host-b**:

```
host-? ~$ cat /etc/systemd/network/04-eth0.network
[Match]
Name=eth0

[Network]
IPv6AcceptRA=yes
LinkLocalAddressing=ipv6
```

**router**:

```
router ~$ cat /etc/systemd/network/04-eth0.network
[Match]
Name=eth0

[Network]
Address=2001:db8:0:10::1/64
IPv6AcceptRA=no
LinkLocalAddressing=ipv6
IPForward=ipv6

router ~$ cat /etc/systemd/network/06-eth1.network
[Match]
Name=eth1

[Network]
Address=2001:db8:0:20::1/64
IPv6AcceptRA=no
LinkLocalAddressing=ipv6
IPForward=ipv6
```

Reboot all nodes and you should have an autoconfigured running simple network.

### Simplifications

To show what's needed I explicitly wrote the options into the network configuration files. But most of them are default settings, so we can just omit them.

**host-a** and **host-b**:

```
host-? ~$ cat /etc/systemd/network/04-eth0.network
[Match]
Name=eth0
```

**router**:

```
router ~$ cat /etc/systemd/network/04-eth0.network
[Match]
Name=eth0
[Network]
Address=2001:db8:0:10::1/64
IPForward=ipv6

router ~$ cat /etc/systemd/network/06-eth1.network
[Match]
Name=eth1
[Network]
Address=2001:db8:0:20::1/64
IPForward=ipv6
```

### Debug

You may need to check if the host gets the correct settings from the router, or there is a router, for example from you internet provider, from that you must know what exactly settings it sends. Then you can start `radvdump` to view the received Router Advertisement. If you start it, just wait a little bit until a Router Advertisement is received. This is it with the default settings from `router`:

```
host-a ~$ sudo radvdump
#
# radvd configuration generated by radvdump 2.18
# based on Router Advertisement from fe80::5054:ff:fe0f:194e
# received by interface eth0
#

interface eth0
{
        AdvSendAdvert on;
        # Note: {Min,Max}RtrAdvInterval cannot be obtained with radvdump
        AdvManagedFlag off;
        AdvOtherConfigFlag off;
        AdvReachableTime 0;
        AdvRetransTimer 0;
        AdvCurHopLimit 64;
        AdvDefaultLifetime 1800;
        AdvHomeAgentFlag off;
        AdvDefaultPreference medium;
        AdvSourceLLAddress on;

        prefix 2001:db8:0:10::/64
        {
                AdvValidLifetime 86400;
                AdvPreferredLifetime 14400;
                AdvOnLink on;
                AdvAutonomous on;
                AdvRouterAddr off;
        }; # End of prefix definition

}; # End of interface definition
```

### Name Resolution

Name resolution over the complete network is only possible with a DNS server. Its setup is a new question and out of scope here. Not having a DNS server available on this simple network is also the reason why we always use ping6 with option `-n` which suppresses querying a DNS server to translate the ip address. Without `-n`, ping6 tries to connect to a DNS server for each request with a timeout. This slows down pinging drastically and isn't usable.

For the local link it is no problem to enable multicast DNS (**mDNS**) so you have name resolution for the direct connected nodes. Just add option

```
MulticastDNS=yes
```

to the `[Network]` section on every nodes `/etc/systemd/network/*.network` file. Then you should be able to

```
host-a ~$ ping6 -n router.local
PING router.local(fe80::5054:ff:fe0f:194e%eth0) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from fe80::5054:ff:fe0f:194e%eth0: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=2.37 ms
64 bytes from fe80::5054:ff:fe0f:194e%eth0: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.799 ms
64 bytes from fe80::5054:ff:fe0f:194e%eth0: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.823 ms
--- snip ---
```

But `ping6 -n host-b.local` will not work from `host-a` because **mDNS** is not routable.

**References:**

- [RfC 4291](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4291) - IP Version 6 Addressing Architecture
- [RfC 4193](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4193) - Unique Local IPv6 Unicast Addresses (ULA)
- [RfC 3849](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3849) - IPv6 Address Prefix Reserved for Documentation
- [RfC 3810](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3810) - Multicast Listener Discovery Version 2 (MLDv2) for IPv6
- [RfC 4862](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4862) - IPv6 Stateless Address Autoconfiguration
- [RfC 4864](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4864) - Local Network Protection for IPv6 (no NAT needed)
- [IANA](https://www.iana.org/assignments/ipv6-multicast-addresses/ipv6-multicast-addresses.xhtml) - IPv6 Multicast Address Space Registry
- [Linux IPv6 HOWTO](https://www.ibiblio.org/pub/Linux/docs/HOWTO/other-formats/html_single/Linux+IPv6-HOWTO.html)
- [IPv6 - Address Types & Formats](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ipv6/ipv6_address_types.htm)